# c++, std::atomic, what is std::memory_order and how to use them?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, memory-model, stdatomic

Can anyone explain what is `std::memory_order` in plain English, and how to use them with `std::atomic<>`?

I found the reference and few examples here, but don't understand at all.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

Comment: +1 very good question. let's hope for some good answers!

Comment: I've found this (quite dense) [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7463092/726300) helpful in the past as an introduction to memory ordering.

Comment: It seems that this topic can go pretty deep. As zvrba has suggested, as a beginner like myself, use the default value "sequential-consistent ordering" may be a good idea.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346487/what-do-each-memory-order-mean

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Can anyone explain what is std::memory_order in plain English,

The best "Plain English" explanation I've found for the various memory orderings is Bartoz Milewski's article on relaxed atomics: http://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/12/01/c-atomics-and-memory-ordering/

And the follow-up post: http://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/12/23/the-inscrutable-c-memory-model/

But note that whilst these articles are a good introduction, they pre-date the C++11 standard and won't tell you everything you need to know to use them safely.

> and how to use them with std::atomic<>?

My best advice to you here is: **don't**. Relaxed atomics are (probably) the trickiest and most dangerous thing in C++11. Stick to `std::atomic<T>` with the default memory ordering (sequential consistency) until you're really, really sure that you have a performance problem that can be solved by using the relaxed memory orderings.

In the second article linked above, Bartoz Milewski reaches the following conclusion:

> I had no idea what I was getting myself into when attempting to reason
>   about C++ weak atomics. The theory behind them is so complex that it’s
>   borderline unusable. It took three people (Anthony, Hans, and me) and
>   a modification to the Standard to complete the proof of a relatively
>   simple algorithm. Imagine doing the same for a lock-free queue based
>   on weak atomics!

Comment: thank you for your advice. As a beginner, I found this very helpful.

Comment: See Jeff Preshing's articles, like [this one about acquire / release](http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/), for excellent intro material that does describe C++11 as well as describing things in terms of the kinds of memory reordering allowed / disallowed.  (e.g. StoreLoad reordering is allowed)

Comment: `relaxed` is much easier to understand: use it when you only need atomicity, not synchronization.  e.g. for a single atomic counter that multiple threads will increment, but that doesn't have any meaning for whether any other data is valid.

Answer (score 57):

The `std::memory_order` values allow you to specify fine-grained constraints on the memory ordering provided by your atomic operations. If you are modifying and accessing atomic variables from multiple threads, then passing the `std::memory_order` values to your operations allow you to **relax** the constraints on the compiler and processor about the order in which the operations on those atomic variables become visible to other threads, and the synchronization effects those operations have on the non-atomic data in your application.

The default ordering of `std::memory_order_seq_cst` is the most constrained, and provides the "intuitive" properties you might expect: if thread A stores some data and then sets an atomic flag using `std::memory_order_seq_cst`, then if thread B sees the flag is set then it can see that data written by thread A. The other memory ordering values do not necessarily provide this guarantee, and must therefore be used very carefully.

The basic premise is: do not use anything other than `std::memory_order_seq_cst` (the default) unless (a) you really **really** know what you are doing, and can **prove** that the relaxed usage is safe in all cases, and (b) your profiler demonstrates that the data structure and operations you are intending to use the relaxed orderings with are a bottleneck.

My book, [C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/book) devotes a whole chapter (45 pages) to the details of the C++ memory model, atomic operations and the `std::memory_order` constraints, and a further chapter (44 pages) to using atomic operations for synchronization in lock-free data structures, and the consequences of relaxed ordering constraints.

My blog entries on [Dekker's algorithm](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing_dekkers_algorithm_with_fences.html) and [Peterson's algorithm](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/petersons_lock_with_C++0x_atomics.html) for mutual exclusion demonstrate some of the issues.

Comment: Relaxed is quite safe for what it's really needed for-- reading isolated values that have no dependent/corresponding values and thus no risk of ordering issues. E.g. a `bool shouldHalt` for asking a thread to stop. In my experience, such isolation is not rare in normal software development. And I argue that for the other case (dependencies between multiple variables), a lock is almost always better in the first place. The only way I see people having difficulty with this is with fancy atomic linked data structures, which is the real thing to watch out for unless there's a serious need.

Comment: In C++ Concurrency in Action (Second Edition), after introducing `std::memory_order` in section 5.2.1, you use a lot of different orderings (even before explaining what they actually do in section 5.3.3) instead of sticking to `std::memory_order_seq_cst` as you suggest in this answer. Does this mean that this answer (or the book) is incorrect, or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: The examples in section 5.2 of the book specify memory orderings to show how you would do so, and what your choices are. For real code, you should stick to `std::memory_order_seq_cst` unless you really know what you are doing *and* it's a proven performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 18):

No. A "plain english" explanation takes 32 pages and can be found [here](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/WRL-95-7.pdf).

If you don't want to read that, you can forget about memory ordering because the page you linked to says that the default is sequentially-consistent ordering, which is "always do the sane thing"-setting.

To use any other setting you *really* have to read and understand the above paper and the examples in it.

Answer (score 5):

In brief, your compiler and CPU may execute instructions in order different from how you have written them. For a single-thread this is not an issue as it will appear correct. For multiple threads on multiple processors this becomes an issue. Memory ordering in C++ restricts what your compiler/CPU can do and fixes such issues.

For example, if you look at my article on [double-check locking](http://mortoray.com/2012/02/28/double-checked-locking-why-doesnt-it-work-and-how-to-fix-it/) you can see how ordering messes with that pattern -- it mention show atomic memory ordering can be used to fix it.

About the reordering itself you can also consider [CPU Reordering](http://mortoray.com/2010/11/18/cpu-reordering-what-is-actually-being-reordered/) -- again, the compiler may also be doing reorders as well.

Be aware that any documents on this topic (including mine) offer speak of theoretical scenarios. The most common CPUs, like x86, have very strong ordering guarantees such that a lot of explicit ordering is simply not needed. Thus even if you don't use the proper C++11 atomics your code will likely still work.

As zvrba mentioned, the topic is actually quite detailed. The linux kernel doc on [memory barriers](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob_plain;f=Documentation/memory-barriers.txt;hb=HEAD) also contains a lot of detailed information.

Answer (score 3):

There is some plain english in GCC wiki. ;)

http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync