# std::atomic<int>: Difference between x.fetch_add(1) and x++;

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, atomic

What is the difference between

```
extern std::atomic<int> x;
int i = x++;
```

and

```
extern std::atomic<int> x;
int i = x.fetch_add(1);
```

I feel like the second version is safer, but I couldn't see any differences in testing between these two versions.

Comment: For future reference, always include the [c++] tag for anything C++. Otherwise a lot of potential answerers won't see it at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is definitely not about the safety = atomicity which is guaranteed for both methods.

The most important difference I think is that `fetch_add()` can take a different memory order argument while for increment operator it is always `memory_order_seq_cst`.

Another obvious difference is that `fetch_add()` can take not only `1` as argument while on the other hand, `operator++` is more likely to be implemented using `lock inc` instruction (though, theoretically nothing prevents a compiler from such an optimization for `fetch_add(1)` as well)

So answering your exact question, there is no any semantically important difference between `x++` and `x.fetch_add(1)`. The [doc says](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/operatorplusplus/):

> This function behaves as if atomic::fetch_add was called with 1 and memory_order_seq_cst as arguments.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that ``x++`` is defined as ``x.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst)``?

Comment: [The other doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith), for reference.

Answer (score 5):

**`x.fetch_add(1)` and `x++` are exactly the same for `std::atomic`**

If you believe cppreference, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith says:

> ```
> T operator++() volatile noexcept; (1)
>
> T* operator++() volatile noexcept; (2)
> ```
>
> 1. Performs atomic pre-increment. Equivalent to `fetch_add(1)+1`.
> 2. Performs atomic post-increment. Equivalent to `fetch_add(1)`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add then documents:

> T fetch_add( T arg,
> std::memory_order order = std::memory_order_seq_cst ) noexcept;

so we see that the `std::memory_order` of `operator++` defaults to `std::memory_order_seq_cst`, which is the stronger one available, see also: [What do each memory_order mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346487/what-do-each-memory-order-mean)

**C++11 standard quotes**

If you don't believe cppreference, the [C++11 N3337 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 29.6.5/33 "Requirements for operations on atomic types" says:

> ```
> C A ::operator++(int) volatile noexcept;
> C A ::operator++(int) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Returns: fetch_add(1)

29.6.5/2 clarifies `C` and `A`:

> - an A refers to one of the atomic types.
> - a C refers to its corresponding non-atomic type

I wasn't able to find it explained clearly but I suppose `Returns: fetch_add(1)` implies that `fetch_add(1)` is called for its side effect of course.

It is also worth looking at the prefix version a bit further:

> ```
> C A ::operator++() volatile noexcept;
> C A ::operator++() noexcept;
> ```
>
> Effects: fetch_add(1)
>
> Returns: fetch_add(1) + 1

which indicates that this one returns the value + 1 like the regular prefix increment for integers.

**GCC 4.8**

[libstdc++-v3/include/std/atomic](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-4_8_2-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/atomic#L594) says `atomic<int>` inherits `__atomic_base<int>`:

```
struct atomic<int> : __atomic_base<int>
```

[libstdc++-v3/include/bits/atomic_base.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-4_8_2-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/atomic_base.h#L387) implements it like:

```
__int_type
operator++(int) noexcept
{ return fetch_add(1); }

__int_type
operator++(int) volatile noexcept
{ return fetch_add(1); }

__int_type
operator++() noexcept
{ return __atomic_add_fetch(&_M_i, 1, memory_order_seq_cst); }

__int_type
operator++() volatile noexcept
{ return __atomic_add_fetch(&_M_i, 1, memory_order_seq_cst); }

_GLIBCXX_ALWAYS_INLINE __int_type
fetch_add(__int_type __i,
memory_order __m = memory_order_seq_cst) noexcept
{ return __atomic_fetch_add(&_M_i, __i, __m); }

_GLIBCXX_ALWAYS_INLINE __int_type
fetch_add(__int_type __i,
memory_order __m = memory_order_seq_cst) volatile noexcept
{ return __atomic_fetch_add(&_M_i, __i, __m); }
```

I do not understand why the postfix calls the `fetch_add` helper and the prefix uses the built-in directly, but in the end they all come down to the GCC intrinsics `__atomic_fetch_add` and `__atomic_add_fetch` which do the real work.