# is it possible that `g_count++` is executed before init work is finished?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

is it possible that `g_count++` is executed before init work is finished? ( I mean, maybe the complier or cpu would change their execution order )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::mutex g_mtx;
int g_count = 0;

void func1()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(g_mtx);
    // init work
    // ...

    g_count++;
}

void func2()
{
    if (g_count > 0)
    {
        // some work that depends on init work
    }
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(g_mtx);
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(func1);
    std::thread t2(func2);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

is it possible that `g_count++` is executed before init work is finished? ( I mean, maybe the complier or cpu would change their execution order )

Comment: Why is your guard at the end of func2? (btw std::scoped_lock is preferred). Anyway there isn't a guarantee that t2 will start after t1. I make it a habit to check func1 has started (condition variable) before creating t2 in these kind of scenarios

Comment: Since the code has a race condition (`func2()` accesses `g_count` without proper synchronization), the code *invokes undefined behavior* which means that as far as the C++ language is concerned, literally anything is possible; in that scenario, you're not expected to be able to draw any conclusions about how the program will behave; you're expected instead to fix the program so that the undefined behavior does not occur.  Then (and only then) will the C++ deities agree to give you any guarantees about what your program will or will not do :)

Comment: No, but func2 makes absolutely no sense.  And the only way to change them to make any sense makes it so they cannot run concurrently which means there's no point in making a two threads

Comment: Sry for my unclear question. I just wondering if the execution order of my code possibly be changed  in `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` lifetime. At the beginning, I wanted to write some code to test, but found it difficulty.

Comment: Why does `func2()` lock the mutex *after* the `if` statement?  As is, you have undefined behaviour due to unsequenced access/modification of `g_count` (as mentioned by Jeremy).   Move the mutex locking to *before* the `if` and that undefined behaviour is eliminated, but there is no guarantee that "init work" is completed before the "some work that depends on init work" (no guarantee as to which thread will lock the mutex first).

Answer (score 3):

> is it possible that `g_count++` is executed before init work is finished?

Yes, but it is impossible to observe that without getting undefined behavior.

And indeed, your code has a "data race" - a kind of undefined behavior caused by writing to a variable in one thread, and reading/writing to it from a different thread, if nothing guarantees that one of the operations will happen before the other.

If `if (g_count > 0)` was guarded by the mutex, the mutex would guarantee that `if` either happens before `g_count++` of after it. Without guarding `if` with the mutex, nothing guarantees that it doesn't happen at the same time as `g_count++`, hence you have UB.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I thought that code within the `std::lock_guard` lifetime will not be changed in execution order. Maybe I should learn more about this.

Comment: @shaunwick Perhaps this will help: [What do each memory_order mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346487/what-do-each-memory-order-mean/70585811#70585811)

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for first thread to have started goes like this :

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

// ofcourse in production code do not use globals ;)
std::mutex g_mtx;
int g_count = 0;

std::mutex g_cv_mtx;
std::condition_variable m_cv;
bool g_thread1_started{false};


void func1()
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> cv_lock{g_cv_mtx};
        g_thread1_started = true;
        m_cv.notify_all();
    }
    
    std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock{g_mtx};
    g_count++;
}

void func2()
{
    if (g_count > 0)
    {
        // some work that depends on init work
    }
    std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock{g_mtx};
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(func1);

    // condition variable ALWAYS wait with a predicate
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> cv_lock{g_cv_mtx};
    m_cv.wait(cv_lock,[&]{ return g_thread1_started; });

    std::thread t2(func2);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```