# In C++, which Standard Library functions (if any) are required to implicitly provided an atomic memory fence?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, memory-barriers

For example, is calling **std::mutex::lock()** required by the Standard to provide a sequentially consistent fence, an acquire fence, or neither?

**cppreference.com** doesn't seem to address this topic.  Is it addressed in any reference documentation that's more easy to use than the Standard or working papers?

Comment: Unless otherwise stated, as this sort of behaviour is exceptional, you should assume no such thing happens. Thread safety is explicitly documented, not implicit.

Comment: `mutex::[un]lock` is weaker than a fence. It's equivalent to a single atomic variable, where `lock` is an acquire load and `unlock` is a release store. Whereas the wording for acq/rel fences effectively makes them promote surrounding atomic operations to the corresponding order. I've attempted an explanation here: [What do each memory_order mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70585811/2752075)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about an easier source, but here's a quote from a note in the standard:

> [...] a call that acquires a mutex will perform an acquire operation on
> the locations comprising the mutex. Correspondingly, a call that releases the same mutex will perform a
> release operation on those same locations. Informally, performing a release operation on A forces prior side
> effects on other memory locations to become visible to other threads that later perform a consume or an
> acquire operation on A.

I *think* that answers the question about memory fences reasonably well (and although it's "only" a note, not a normative part of the standard, I'd say it's as reliable a description of the standard as any other site could hope to provide).

Comment: Thanks, I hope a contributor to cppreference.com will see this and add the info.

Comment: @WaltK don't we say it in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Acquire_operation ? To be far at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock and other Mutex pages we only say "synchronizes-with"

Answer (score 3):

`std::atomic` and `std::mutex` *operations* never require full 2-way *fences*.  That does happen in practice on some ISAs as an implementation detail, notably x86, but not AArch64.

Even `std::atomic<T>` atomic RMWs  with the default `memory_order_seq_cst` aren't as strong as full 2-way fences, I think.  On real ISAs where SC RMWs can be done without being much stronger than required ([specifically AArch64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70249647/the-strong-ness-of-x86-store-instruction-wrt-sc-drf)), I'm not sure they stop relaxed operations on opposite sides from reordering with each other.  (Happening between the load and store parts of the atomic RMW).

---

As Jerry Coffin says, **taking a `std::mutex`** is only an acquire *operation* in the ISO C++ standard, not an acquire *fence*.  It's not like `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire)`, it's only required to be as strong as `foo.exchange(std::memory_order_acquire)`.

The lack of mention of requiring a 2-way *fence* makes it clear that one isn't required or guaranteed by the standard.  An acquire *operation* like taking a mutex allows 1-way reordering with itself, so relaxed operations before/after it can potentially reorder with each other.  (That's why [fences and operations are different things](https://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect).)

Being any stronger than that is an implementation detail.  For example on x86 where any atomic RMW operation is a full barrier, waiting for the store buffer to drain itself, and for all earlier loads to complete, before RMWing the cache line.  So it's like a `std::atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst)` tied to the `foo.exchange()`; in fact a dummy `lock add byte [rsp], 0` is how most compilers implement that C++ fence, because unfortunately `mfence` is slower on most CPUs.

**Taking a mutex always require an atomic RMW,** but some machines can do that in ways that allow limited reordering with surrounding operations.  e.g. AArch64 can use `ldaxr` (sequential-acquire load-linked) / `stxr` (plain store-conditional, not `stlxr` with release semantics) to implement `.exchange(acquire)` or `.compare_exchange_weak(acquire)`.  See an example [compiling to asm for AArch64 on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:19,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:19,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:19),source:%27%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A%0A//+newer+GCC+won!%27t+inline+these+to+LL/SC+retry+loops+with+old+-mcpu%3D%0A//+It!%27s+holding+out+for+dynamic+dispatch+to+single-instruction+versions%0A//++in+case+the+code+does+run+on+newer+CPUs.%0A//+But+with+GCC6+for+example+we+can+see+LL/SC+loops.%0A%0Aint+exch_acquire(std::atomic%3Cint%3E+%26a)%7B%0A++++return+a.fetch_add(1,+std::memory_order_acquire)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+exch_sc(std::atomic%3Cint%3E+%26a)%7B%0A++++return+a.fetch_add(1)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+exch_relaxed(std::atomic%3Cint%3E+%26a)%7B%0A++++return+a.fetch_add(1,+std::memory_order_relaxed)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.96945977052822,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm64g1220,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-mcpu%3Dcortex-a76%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27ARM64+gcc+12.2.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:29.119181870570564,l:%274%27,m:62.510322047894306,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+ARM64+gcc+12.2.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:37.489677952105694,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:30.54892186520601,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm64g640,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-mcpu%3Dcortex-a53%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27ARM64+gcc+6.4+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:33.481618364265785,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), and also *[atomic exchange with memory_order_acquire and memory_order_release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73758855/atomic-exchange-with-memory-order-acquire-and-memory-order-release/73759315#73759315)* and *[For purposes of ordering, is atomic read-modify-write one operation or two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65568185/for-purposes-of-ordering-is-atomic-read-modify-write-one-operation-or-two)*