# How do you use std::atomic to achieve thread-safety without locking mutexes?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread, stdatomic

I know, that in some situations you can avoid having to lock mutexes (`std::mutex`) by using `std::atomic`, thus increasing performance.

Can you **name a situation like this**, and preferably **show some example code** on how to do this (how do you use `std::atomic`)?

Also, when I lock a mutex, the performance degrades because other threads are unable to continue doing their work for the period of time the mutex is locked. Is this the only issue with a mutex? I mean, **is locking/unlocking a mutex an expensive operation** or it's just about what I mentioned above?

Comment: Do you understand the notion of an atomic operation? If you do, then you'll see that if you can ensure that an operation is atomic, there is no need to guard such an operation with a mutex.

Comment: Edited to make it narrower, hope it clears the question.

Comment: Try taking a look through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553591/c-stdatomic-what-is-stdmemory-order-and-how-to-use-them). If you haven't already I would strongly suggest reading [C++ Concurrency In Action](http://www.amazon.com/C-Concurrency-Action-Practical-Multithreading/dp/1933988770). The [author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5597/anthony-williams) was one of the primary maintainers of [`boost::Thread`](http://www.boost.org/users/people/anthony_williams.html). They have a whole chapter (chpt 5) on the C++ memory model, and atomic types.

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461484/memory-model-ordering-and-visibility/7463092#7463092)

Comment: Since this question still pops up out of the few related, I offer as an example a shared mutex / shared lock code based on atomic and memory ordering that I wrote after studying this subject a little. https://github.com/shutow/shared_mutex